# How Does Twitter Bootstrap Achieve Automatic Column Stacking As Width Decreases?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap 3, you can use the following code to build a row with 3 columns that collapse onto one another as the screen width decreases:

```
<div class = 'row'>
    <div class = 'col-md-4'>
         Some text
    </div>
    <div class = 'col-md-4'>
         Some text
    </div>
    <div class = 'col-md-4'>
         Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

I am working on a project right now where I would like to achieve the same effect, but without having to load Bootstrap.

How does Bootstrap achieve the 'stacking' effect that you would get from the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is that the width of the columns work on percentages. So in your example the width of each column might be 33.333% and then you use a media query to say at a certain resolution the width of items change and they stop floating or whatever else you want to make them do on a smaller resolution.

Here's an example of a media query where any device with a resolution with a maximum width of 767px will be affected.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

    .col-md-4 {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }

}
```

Here's a great article by Ethan Marcotte who is pretty much credited with creating what we now know as responsive web design:

http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/